# mysql update a summary table by selecting and counting multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, join, set

I have a table called `summary` to record the sales record of different shops (tables), `shopA`, `shopB`, `shopC`, (Say I have more than 100 shops...)
All tables have `date` column.
so, for example

```
**Summary**
|Date|Total_sales|Shops_sales > 1000dollars|

**ShopA** has 2 columns
|Date      |Sales|

|2016-03-16|1500 |
|2016-03-15|1100 |

**ShopB** has 2 columns
|Date      |Sales|
|2016-03-17|900  |
|2016-03-16|1200 |
|2016-03-15|600  |

**ShopC** has 2 columns
|Date      |Sales|
|2016-03-17|900  |
|2016-03-16|800  |
|2016-03-15|600  |
```

I want the `Summary` table like this...

```
|Date      |Total_sales|Shops_sales > 1000dollars|
|2016-03-17|1800       |0
|2016-03-16|3500       |2
|2016-03-15|2300       |1
```

I have tried...

```
update Summary 
set Total_sales= 
(
SELECT ( 
ShopA.Sales+ 
ShopB.Sales+
ShopC.Sales+  
)
AS Total_sales
FROM ShopA
LEFT JOIN ShopB ON ShopA.Date = ShopB.Date
LEFT JOIN ShopC ON ShopA.Date = ShopC.Date
GROUP BY ShopA.Date order by ShopA.Date desc LIMIT 1) order by Date desc LIMIT 1;
```

However, I could only update the latest row rather than all rows. Between, if ShopA did not update the latest sales, say...

```
ShopA.Date = 2016-03-16
ShopB.Date = 2016-03-17
ShopC.Date = 2016-03-17
```

Then, the `Total_sales` calculation is not updated correctly. So, what can I do to make it correctly?

Another question is: How can I count the `Shops_Sale > 1000` dollars by using `SET`? I found many answer by using select but rarely found any about using `SET`. I found `JOIN` has its limitation with less than 60 tables, how can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you keep one table per each shop..?

Comment: Actually, I have many different information in each table. Say,  customers visited, number of products sold (sorted by brand names), etc...

Comment: Does each shop table have a different set of columns?

Comment: All tables have same structure.

Comment: In that case maybe consider using a single table for all shops with a shop_id column identifying the shop. It's not an answer for your question but I think it's good advice. It will make your queries simpler and is generally the proper way to work with a relational database...